# Change width of the 'div' after rotation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Please check [MY BUGGY DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/fjckls/4y0Lddnr/3)

```js
$( ".circ-part" ).hover(
   function() {
     $(this).width(90);
   }, function() {
     $(this).width(60);
   }
 );

var   angle = 0, centerX = 120, centerY = 150,
      total = $(".circ-part").length,
      step = (2 * Math.PI) / total,
      radius = 100;

for (var i = 0; i < total; i++) {
    // positions around circle
    var xposition = centerX + Math.cos(angle) * radius,
        yposition = centerY + Math.sin(angle) * radius;
    
    // rotation to center point
    var dx = centerX - xposition,
        dy = centerY - yposition,
        rotation = Math.atan2(dy, dx) * 180 / Math.PI; //radians to degrees

    var element =  $( ".circ-part:eq(" + i + ")" );
    element.css({ 
      "transform": 
        "translate(" + xposition + "px," + yposition + "px)" + 
        "rotate(" + rotation +"deg)" 
    });

    // increase angle 
    angle += step;
  };
```

```css
*{ margin:0; padding:0;}
.circ-part{
    background: red;
    position: absolute;
    width:60px;height: 30px;
    transform-origin: left center;
}

.first{
    background:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrap">
  <div class="circ-part first">x</div>
  <div class="circ-part">x</div>
  <div class="circ-part">x</div>
  <div class="circ-part">x</div>
  <div class="circ-part">x</div>
</div>
```

I place `divs` around circle and distribute them evenly. On hover I want to change width of the `div`.

UPDATE:
I have added css

```
transform-origin: left center;
```

Now it works only other way around - I need elements to expand outwards...

Answer (score 1):

You are increasing the width, but not adjusting the position.  Try this:

```
$( ".circ-part" ).hover(
   function() {
     $(this).width(90);
     $(this).css({left: -15});
   }, function() {
     $(this).width(60);
     $(this).css({left: 0});
   }
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to play with `transform-origin:`.

[Info here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin)

Just adding `transform-origin: 0 0;` to `circ-part` in the css of your fiddle removes the movement. However, it looks like crap. You'll have to tune it to your needs.